# How to make a difference between the portfolio list, and a portfolio item?

Tags: css

I am using the portfolio possibilities of WordPress and I am trying to change the style. However, in the list (the one that I see at `site.com/portfolio`) I see that the `article` element has the same styling as in the portfolio item (the one that I see at `site.com/portfolio/someitem`). However, I want to style them differently.

So, how can I discern between the portfolio list and the items, in styling?

Comment: Check the `body`'s class names. For single portfolio pages, it should have `single-portfolio` in the class names list. And `archive-portfolio` for portfolio archives. You can then create CSS rules like `body.single-portfolio article { /*styles here*/ }`, but that's of course a simplified example. And I'm assuming the portfolios are custom post type of `portfolio`.

Comment: @SallyCJ unfortunately, both have the same classes. I dont even see the `single-portfolio` and `archive-portfolio` classes.

Comment: Try editing the [the (single and/or archive) template files](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates), if you can. You can wrap the `article` items in a `special-class` and create specific CSS rules that target the `special-class`. E.g. `.special-class { color: #666; }`

Comment: You can also *inspect* the corresponding `article` element on `/portfolio` and `/portfolio/someitem` and try to find unique classes, and use one of them to change/customize their appearance on the different URLs. You can also use *filter* to add the `single-portfolio`/`archive-portfolio` class to the `body` tag.

Comment: @SallyCJ there are no unique classes. How does that filter method work?

Comment: The filter is [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) - check it out, and you should be able to understand how it works. (I can show sample code, if you want.)

Comment: If you're actually looking for a CSS-only solution (no PHP coding), you'd need to try to inspect the HTML of the `article` element, its container element, etc., and find a unique class name and then create the CSS rules as I've mentioned before.

Comment: @SallyCJ the solution was to look at the `body` element, that is where the differences were. I added a `body.archive-jetpack-portfolio article` CSS rule and it looks like I want now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome. :) (You should write an answer and accept it, so that people know the question has been answered.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer lied in the fact that not the `article` elements differ, but the `body` element. So, I added

```
body.archive-jetpack-portfolio article {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

to my CSS, and it all looks fine now.

Comment: If I may give a tip.. you should use `article.{CLASS NAME}` so that the CSS rules are applied only to the *appropriate* `article` elements and not all `article`s in all parts of the page. Unless you want it that way. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ I know. I'll change it, when I run into it :).